# matplotlib colorbar in subplots: labels are vanishing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am developing some code to produce an arbitrary number of 2D plots (maps and simple contour plots) on a figure. The matplotlib subplots routine works great for this. In the simplified example below, everything works as it should. However, in my real application - which uses the exact same commands for subplots, contourf and colorbar, only that these are dispersed across several routines - the labels on the colorbars are not showing up (the color patches seem to be ok though). Even after hours of reading documentation and searching the web, I don't even have a clue where I could start looking for what the problem is. If I have my colorbar instance (cbar), I should be able to find out if the ticklabel position makes sense, if the ticklabels are set to visible, if my font settings make sense, etc.... But how do I actually check these properties? Has anyone encountered similar problems already? (and even better: found a solution?) Oh yes: if I manually create a new figure and axes in the actual plotting routine (where the contourf command is issued), then it will work again. But that means losing all control over the figure layout etc. Could it be that I am not passing my axes instance correctly? Here is what I do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)
row, col = getCurrent(...)
plotMap(x, y, data, ax=ax[row,col], ...)
```

Then, inside plotMap:

```
c = ax.contourf(x, y, data, ...)
ax.figure.colorbar(c, ax=ax, orientation="horizontal", shrink=0.8)
```

As said above, the example below with simplified plots and artificial data works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.,360.,5.)*np.pi/180.
y = np.arange(0.,360.,5.)*np.pi/180.
data = np.zeros((y.size, x.size))
for i in range(x.size):
    data[:,i] = np.sin(x[i]**2*y**2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
contour = ax[0].contourf(x, y, data)
cbar = ax[0].figure.colorbar(contour, ax=ax[0], orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.8)
contour = ax[1].contourf(x, y, data, levels=[0.01,0.05,0.1,0.05])
cbar = ax[1].figure.colorbar(contour, ax=ax[1], orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.8)
plt.show()
```

Thanks for any help!

*Addition after some further poking around:*

```
for t in cbar.ax.get_xticklabels():
    print t.get_position(), t.get_text(), t.get_visible()
```

shows me the correct text and visible=True, but all positions are (0.,0.). Could this be a problem?

BTW: axis labels are also missing sometimes... and I am using matplotlib version 1.1.1 with python 2.7.3 on windows.

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer so this gets closed? You can accept your own answer later.

Comment: for future reference `plt.tight_layout()` (also a method of `figure` object) often works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

OK - I could track it down: matplotlib is working as it should!
The error was embedded in a utility routine that adds some finishing touches to each page (=figure) once the given number of plot panels has been produced. In this routine I wanted to hide empty plot panels (i.e. on the last page) and I did this with

```
ax = fig.axes
for i in range(axCurrent, len(ax)):
    ax[i].set_axis_off()
```

However, axCurrent was already reset to zero when the program entered this routine for any page but the last, hence the axes were switched off for all axes in figure. Adding

```
if axCurrent > 0:
```

before the *for i...* solves the problem.

Sorry if I stole anyone's time. Thanks anyway to everyone who was considering to help!